# Tooltip is not showing my content on hover on first time but displaying on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

My code is here

```
<a href="", class="cancel-invitation-from-other" title="Close" onmouseover = "show_bookclub_book_tooltip('Decline invitation','cancel-invitation-from-other');" data-placement="top"></a>
```

and javascript is

```
function show_bookclub_book_tooltip(text, div_class){       
    $("."+div_class).attr({
        "data-placement": "top",
        "data-toggle": "tooltip",
        "data-original-title": text
    }).tooltip('show');      
}
```

it returns tooltip on second time but first time this display `"close"` text but i want to display on first time my content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/, you're probably getting the following error the first time:

```
Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'
```

To avoid that, try:

```
function show_bookclub_book_tooltip(text, div_class){       
    $("."+div_class).attr({
        "data-placement": "top",
        "data-toggle": "tooltip",
        "data-original-title": text
    }).tooltip().tooltip('open');      
}
```